# Server takes 30 seconds to respond to simple request. DoS?

Tags: denial-of-service

I'm testing a web app and noticed that by converting a particular GET request to a POST request the server takes about 30 seconds to respond and then returns a generic error page (compared to the original GET request which took the server about 300ms to respond).

What are the chances that this could be used for a DoS attack and how serious would that be?

I'm asking because I'm hesitating to submit this bug to the app owner who is running a bug bounty program as I do want to avoid negative feedback/reputation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are the chances that this could be used for a DoS attack and how
>   serious would that be?

The chances are good. If a specially crafted request causes an unusually long waiting time that's a good indicator that you're occupying a thread on the server and found a potential Denial of Service attack vector. DoS bugs often get overlooked in web applications but there are quite a few ways in which they can occur ([SQL wildcard attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Wildcard_Attacks_(OWASP-DS-001)), pending network requests, etc.). Against many web frameworks there have been published advisories on DoS flaws, like [this one](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/40288/) for Wordpress.

The severity obviously depends on the service they're running. A small web shop could lose a few potential customers - on the other hand, for a bitcoin trading site it could result in great money loss.

> I'm asking because I'm hesitating to submit this bug to the app owner
>   who is running a bug bounty program as I do want to avoid negative
>   feedback/reputation.

Bug Bounty Programs often explicitly exclude DoS vulnerabilities from their scope. But that doesn't mean they're not interested - rather, vendors are often afraid to encourage attacks which would likely impact their services (which a DoS clearly does).

**I would still report it.** BBPs have rewarded DoS flaws in the past, for example [here](https://hackerone.com/reports/98083) or [here](https://hackerone.com/reports/136221). I'd clarify that you have not actively been looking for DoS bugs but found behavior that strongly indicates that a DoS attack vector might be there. I'm sure they're interested to have a look at this if they recognize you as a responsible researcher.

There is also [this OWASP guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Denial_of_Service) on testing for DoS vulnerabilities, but as said, I wouldn't *actively* do it without permission. That wouldn't be the first time someone [got banned from a BBP](https://twitter.com/nnwakelam/status/501178260223303680).

Comment: Great answer! A minor detail: Not all servers use one thread per request. If the server is running e.g. Node that is not the case.